# getting a report using karma in gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a test task, here it is:

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    return new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }).start();
});
```

which is working fine. The issue is that it produces very limited output:

```
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS
```

which is fine on the command line. However I would like a more detailed report produced in some file(s) of which tests were run and which succeeded/failed etc. I am not looking for some xml or anything special. Just a text file that would be readable to a human that would open the file.

I know there are many reporters to choose from but I am having trouble choosing the best one. Additionally I am not sure how to integrate it into the gulp task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me google it for you – https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html-reporter – you must extend `karma.conf.js` file and setup additional reporter in it

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski =) Thanks, works great.

Comment: @pQuestions123 Are you using Jasmine as your testing framework?

Comment: @Nocomm Yes, I am using Jasmine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to produce an output file and/or are using PhantomJS, then I would suggest using karma-html-reporter : `npm install --save-dev karma-html-reporter`

   - In `karma.conf.js`: `reporters: ['html']`
2. If you are launching your tests in a browser like Chrome or Firefox, then I like karma-jasmine-html-reporter.  To see the output, you'll need to click the DEBUG button in the top-right corner of the browser : `npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter`

   - In `karma.conf.js`: `reporters: ['html']`
3. Or you can use both : `npm install --save-dev karma-html-reporter Nocomm/karma-jasmine-html-reporter`

   - In `karma.conf.js`: `reporters: ['html', 'kjhtml']`

As far as Gulp is concerned, you can leverage the `karma` node_module instead of having to install `gulp-karma`.  You will need to install `gulp-jasmine` with npm.  I like [Gulp4.x](http://blog.reactandbethankful.com/posts/2015/05/01/how-to-install-gulp-4/), but you have to specify the version of gulp you want when you install it with npm; the link explains how to do so. Gulp 4.X gives you the option to run tasks in parallel or sequentially.  If you use an earlier version of gulp, then omit the `gulp.series` from the last statement, and instead encapsulate the two tasks with a list: `('jasmine', 'karma')`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    karma = require('karma').Server,
    jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');

gulp.task('karma', function(done) {
    new karma({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: false
    }, done).start();
});

gulp.task('jasmine', function() {
    return gulp.src('client/tests/**/*.spec.js')
        .pipe(jasmine());
});

gulp.task('test', gulp.series(
    'jasmine',
    'karma'
));
```

Then just run `gulp test`.